# s4cmd sync two buckets access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, s3cmd

I am trying to sync two s3 buckets:

```
s4cmd --dry-run sync s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/gtex s3://rnaseq.toil.20k/gtex
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
[Exception] An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
[Thread Failure] An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

The source bucket is publicly available. The second bucket is mine and I have access to it:

```
[centos@ip-172-30-3-12 data]$ s4cmd ls s3://rnaseq.toil.20k/
                 DIR s3://rnaseq.toil.20k/gtex/
                 DIR s3://rnaseq.toil.20k/pnoc/
                 DIR s3://rnaseq.toil.20k/target/
                 DIR s3://rnaseq.toil.20k/tcga/
```

Also I cannot `ls` on the source bucket using `s4cmd` but I can using `s3cmd`:

```
[centos@ip-172-30-3-12 data]$ s4cmd ls s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/gtex
[Exception] An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
[Thread Failure] An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

[centos@ip-172-30-3-12 data]$ s3cmd ls --requester-pays s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/gtex
                       DIR   s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/gtex/
2016-06-03 17:02    435553   s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/gtex-manifest
```

What could be going wrong? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you running that command?

Comment: On an EC2 instance.

Comment: You said you have access to that bucket? Can you paste what policy your account has for the S3?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. (Don't know if it matters but I am not the admin). But I have showed in my question that I have access to both buckets by doing s3cmd ls.

Comment: Are you able to go to the bucket to which you have access and see its content from the AWS Console?

Comment: Yes I have showed that I can do ls on it but only when I use s3cmd with --requester-pays argument.

Comment: Try this command and see if it works "s4cmd sync --acl-public s3://source-bucket/ s3://target-bucket/"

Comment: Consider using the official aws-cli command set tools for S3: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/ In my case it work like a charm.

Comment: @error2007s I get this error: `s4cmd.py: error: no such option: --acl-public`

Comment: @Conti I was trying to use s4cmd because it is supposed to be faster in copying files between buckets.

Comment: Do you have the full URL of the public bucket?

Comment: @error2007s I just know the s3 bucket is `s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/gtex` and it is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the s3cmd behavior, use wildcards:

```
s4cmd sync s3://bucket/path/dirA/* s3://bucket/path/dirB/
```

Note s4cmd doesn't support dirA without trailing slash indicating dirA/* as what rsync supported.

So in you case you have to use.

```
s4cmd --dry-run sync s3://cgl-rnaseq-recompute-fixed/gtex/* s3://rnaseq.toil.20k/gtex
```

Check this documentation for s4cmd it is very helpful.

https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd